# Confusion: Power Bank and Mobile Charging

Tags: power-supply, power, charging

MI Power Bank 10400 mAh rated power bank. It has 93% conversion rate. It uses the USB standard to charge phones, so I am assuming a 5V output voltage. So the total energy 'content' = \$10.4A \times 5V = 52\$ Wh. Energy that can be converted = \$52 \times 0.93 = 48.\$
Now an Iphone 5S battery is rated to be \$5.92\$ Wh.

So, the total number of full Iphone 5S 'full charges' should be \$48 \div 5.92 = 8.1\$. We should thus be able to charge an Iphone 5S \$8.1\$ times.

But, as you can see on the MI Power Bank page, it says, it can completely charge the Iphone only \$4.5\$ times.

What am I missing?

[[Mi 10400 mAh Power Bank](http://www.flipkart.com/mi-10400-mah-power-bank/p/itmeyktwtmdwptvf?pid=ACCDYYQZQJCYEHCB&srno=b_1&ref=8d165bb9-9ed6-43be-b67c-a238a3d600ba)]
[[IPhone 5S specs](http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_5s-5685.php)]

Comment: I don't think this question is off topic. The user is not asking how to use the electronic devices, but is asking about how the manufacturer calculated certain characteristics of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power bank is rated for 10.4Ah. To get the WattHours of the device out you must multiply the capacity of the battery by its nominal voltage (not 5V, the output voltage). For a lithium cell, this is usually 3.7V.

3.7V*10.4Ah = 38.5Wh for bank capacity.

To charge an iPhone, you need 5V, the device is only 93% efficient turning the battery's 3.7V into 5V so now the energy capacity is 38.5Wh*.93 = 35.8Wh.

35.8Wh/5.92Wh = 6, **still a discrepancy**.

The iPhone internal circuitry now has to take that 5V input and convert it to its desired nominal battery voltage which is probably around 3.7V. There will be more conversion losses here, and it is impossible to say exactly how much. Even if we knew the exact efficiency of the iPhone circuitry the numbers still wouldn't work out perfectly as explained below.

A battery's capacity is never a concrete number, and varies with temperature, discharge rate and many other external effects. Maybe the 10.4Ah is only true if the load is 500mA or less. It was likely determined by the manufacturer that a fully charged bank could only charge that model phone 4.5 times through testing or simulation of their battery makeup.

Comment: 6 is a reasonably close to 4.5. Maybe not, but at least closer than 8.1. I can live with that. One more thing: I don't think that how the losses when the IPhone outputs its stored energy will come into picture. Suppose it is switched off while charging. When completely charged, the charger is plugged out, the battery is drained. Then, the phone is again switched off and charged. My question is still valid. We don't care how the IPhone utilizes its energy, do we? We only care how it is being charged. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RedJohn The device you linked to outputs 5V. To charge an iPhone battery that 5V must be converted to a lower voltage to properly charge it, done inside by the cell phone. You cannot conserve 100% of the power when doing this, some is lost as heat. 80-95% are common converter efficiencies and make the 4.5 number quite reasonable.

Comment: But that converter efficiency is 93% right? It says in the specs 'Up to 93% conversion rate'. I might agree that to charge the phone, you might need to convert 5V to 3.8V, but isn't the energy loss there indicated in the 93%?

Comment: @RedJohn No the 93% is the converter efficiency inside the handheld battery module. To go from the battery voltage to 5V output voltage is 93% efficient. There is then another converter inside the cell phone to take the handheld battery module's 5V output and make it something lower for its circuitry. That could be anywhere from 80-95%. It is unique to the cellphone.

Comment: Alright. I'll accept it assuming that you know what you are saying.

Comment: My charging fairphone draws at most 1A. Empirically this bank https://tinyurl.com/yboft4xk can support my phone for at most 8 hours, significantly less than what I expect from the 15Ah (lowest) specified capacity of the site. Even when factoring in 3.7/5 (== 11.1 hours at 1A). Am I missing something? I am mostly interested in charging time, instead of cycles, since I continuously charge while bicycling with GPS through Europe. The more days I can stay in the 'wilderness', safely guided by my phone, the more fun I have, hence this question.

Answer (score 1):

The 10,400Ah rating is for the Li-ion cells themselves which have a 3.7V nominal voltage. This gives a final result of about 38.5Wh. You then have to deal with both the efficiency of the power bank *and* of the iPhone charging circuitry. Doing all the math gives you approximately 5, which is in line with their claims.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but your answer confused me even more. Firstly, what do you mean by "The 10,400Ah rating is for the Li-ion cells themselves which have a 3.7V nominal voltage." Moreover, why do we care about the Power Bank's internal structure? We know its output voltage, we know its current rating. Shouldn't that be sufficient? Next, you somehow came arrived at the value of 5. I don't see how you did that. Can you mention the math involved? :-/

Comment: We *shouldn't* have to care about the internal structure, but they have decided to expose it to us. The power bank has 4 2600mAh 18650 Li-ion cells (as most do), which results in 10,400mAh. 38.5Wh⋅.93⋅.8/5.92Wh ~= 4.84

Comment: Where does the \$0.8\$ in your calculation come from?

Comment: It's a conservative estimate for the efficiency of the iPhone charging circuitry.